# change div to input on-click polymer without jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer

I have a paper-card containing user data that when I click the "edit" button, I want the data displayed to change into text boxes so that I can edit the data and save when clicking "save".

I have seen something similar in JQuery, however I am wanting to avoid using this.

Any thoughts?

```
<paper-card>
  <div class="card-content">
    <div class="bodyHeaderText">Personal</div>
    <div class="bodyNormalText">Name: Robert Jones{{user.FUllName}}</div>
    <div class="bodyNormalText">DOB: 21/06/1987{{user.dateofbirth}}</div>
    <div class="bodyNormalText">Age: 30{{user.age}}</div>
    <div class="bodyNormalText">Gender: Male{{user.gender}}</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-actions"
    <paper-icon-button icon="create">edit mode</paper-icon-button>
  </div>
</paper-card>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two paper-card elements. One with text and one with input boxes. Use iron-pages to switch between them by clicking on the edit/save button and changing a variable (_view in the example below).

```
<iron-pages attr-for-selected="data-view" selected="{{_view}}">

  <paper-card data-view="default">
    <!-- TEXT -->
  </paper-card>

  <paper-card data-view="edit">
    <!-- INPUTS -->
  </paper-card>

</iron-pages>
```

Comment: Thanks Rickard. The iron-pages way of doing things is something that I've only recently picked up and seems like a good way of doing things, so it's nice to be reaffirmed in my new thoughts :-D

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing your own component, you can use [`paper-datatable`](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/David-Mulder/paper-datatable). It works in the same way as you want. [`demo-link`](http://david-mulder.github.io/paper-datatable/components/paper-datatable/demo/paper-datatable-card/full-implementation.html)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Holy crap @Mr.7, that's like... exactly what I've been needing for ages! Thanks

Comment: It's a good point you have give me, but it hasn't answered my question in the instance that I'm not wanting to implement a datatable...